# how can i quit a while loop netbean

Tags: java, netbeans

how can i quit this while loop , the statement break is useless~

```
while(rs.next()) {

    String uname=rs.getString("User_ID"); 
    String password=rs.getString("User_PW");
    String cusType=rs.getString("CUS_TYPE");
    if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(password))){
        if (cusType.equals("1")){
         Account_Info_IND accountInfo = new Account_Info_IND();
         accountInfo.setVisible(true);
         this.dispose();
         **BREAK;**
        }
        else {
           Account_Info_COMP accountInfo1 = new Account_Info_COMP();
          accountInfo1.setVisible(true);
          this.dispose();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean: *the statement break is useless*?

Comment: The likely reason `break` is useless here, is it's not getting called.  In fact, a better solution would be to build a better query

Comment: i want to quit this while loop when it satisfy the condition of if statement, so i put a "break " in the if statement but system say error~

Comment: What do you mean *system say error~*?  You are making it very difficult to understand you.

Comment: What i want is quit the while loop when the if condition met~

Comment: I'll ask again: what do you mean: *system say error~*?

Comment: I know this already has an accepted answer but I have to say, I've never seen a break; statement used as **BREAK;**....ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you think the `break` statement is useless, and you have not properly explained what went wrong with it.  But using the `break` statement is a perfectly valid way of exiting a loop.

As an example, run the following code snippet to see that it works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0
>   1
>   2

Maybe by looking at the above code you'll be able to figure out what went wrong with your code.

For what it's worth, I completely agree with MadProgrammer's comment that by writing a proper query that accepts the necessary parameters, you probably wouldn't even need to have the condition inside your loop.